# How to render one to many relationships to XML with PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, select, one-to-many

I have several many to many relationships in my schema. For example, a package has many taskgroups, taskgroups in turn have many tasks. All tables are linked together via many to many tables, holding for instance the primary key of package and the primary key of taskgroup. (I know this is not strictly needed, since XML is one to many, but I couldn't think of a better structure).

Is it possible to get the query result as XML, reflecting the one-to-many structure? So, the result should be like this:

```
<package id=1>
  <taskgroup id=1>
    <task id=1>
    <task id=2>
  </taskgroup>
  <taskgroup id=2>
    <task id=3>
  </taskgroup>
</package>
```

I have managed to get part of what I want by using the `XMLELEMENT()` and `XMLATTRIBUTE()` functions to get all the tasks. Like so:

```
    SELECT XMLELEMENT(name task,
      XMLATTRIBUTES(p.name as packageName),
        XMLELEMENT(name description, t.description),
        XMLELEMENT(name tutorial,
          XMLELEMENT(name someTaskChild1, t.data1)),
        XMLELEMENT(name objectives,
          XMLELEMENT(name someTaskChild2, t.data2)),
    ) 
    FROM packages p
    INNER JOIN package_taskgroup pt ON p.id = pt.package_id
    INNER JOIN taskgroups tg on pt.taskgroup_id = tg.id
    INNER JOIN taskgroup_task tt on tg.id = tt.taskgroup_id
    INNER JOIN tasks t on tt.task_id = t.id
    WHERE p.id = somePackageId AND tg.id = someTaskGroupId
```

The question is how to group these tasks into their parent table elements?

Comment: I have never used the XMLATTRIBUTES / XMLELEMENT functions in postgres. What does the output look like? Just an ordinary table with xml-elements?

Comment: The output is an xml string. :) I don't have an ORM available for the project I currently work on, and the code is so strongly tied to XML that I pretty much have to provide that. It would be so helpful if the database could actually produce the required xml output.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.id as pack_id,
       XMLELEMENT(name taskgroup,
                  XMLATTRIBUTES(tg.id as id),
                  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(name task,
                         XMLATTRIBUTES(t.id as id)) as xml_task_group
FROM packages p
JOIN package_taskgroup pt ON p.id = pt.package_id
JOIN taskgroups tg on pt.taskgroup_id = tg.id
JOIN taskgroup_task tt on tg.id = tt.taskgroup_id
JOIN tasks t on tt.task_id = t.id
WHERE p.id = somePackageId 
GROUP BY p.id, tg.id
```

This will give you all the task groups for the `p.id` you specified.

Then:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(name package, 
                  XMLATTRIBUTES(pack_id as id),
                  XMLAGG(xml_task_group))
FROM (previous SELECT here)
```

This will give you the structure you specified.

Details: [XMLAGG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), [XML functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html)

Joined select will look like this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(name package, 
                  XMLATTRIBUTES(pack_id as id),
                  XMLAGG(xml_task_group))
FROM (SELECT p.id as pack_id,
             XMLELEMENT(name taskgroup,
                        XMLATTRIBUTES(tg.id as id),
                        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(name task,
                                          XMLATTRIBUTES(t.id as id)
                       ))) as xml_task_group
      FROM packages p
      JOIN package_taskgroup pt ON p.id = pt.package_id
      JOIN taskgroups tg on pt.taskgroup_id = tg.id
      JOIN taskgroup_task tt on tg.id = tt.taskgroup_id
      JOIN tasks t on tt.task_id = t.id
      WHERE p.id = somePackageId 
      GROUP BY p.id, tg.id) t
GROUP BY pack_id
```

I simply copied the first select into `FROM` clause of the second.

Comment: I think you've pointed me in the right direction(upvote for that), but I'm still a little confused as to how to join these sub selects together. Will try some more and set yours as the answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Sorry for harping, but: ERROR:  column "t.pack_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:   XMLATTRIBUTES(pack_id as id),

Comment: Added a GROUP BY t.pack_id at the bottom and that seemed to resolve the error. Going over the output now. Note also that there's two missing closing parentheses by `) as xml_task_group`.

Comment: @averagejoe Updated the answer. I haven't tested it initially, so having some simple mistakes is natural.

Comment: Mistakes: yes, I was just pointing them out for others to see if they also found your answer useful. Marked as The Answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT 
     T0."Mail",
     T0."UserName", 
     (SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(name Screens, 
                               XMLELEMENT(name "IN1_ID","IN1."ID"),
                               XMLELEMENT(name "IN1_Name", IN1."Name")
                              )
                    ) 
             FROM "Advertisement"."Screen" IN1 
             WHERE T0."ID" = IN1."PlatformID"
    ) AS Screens 
    FROM "Sales"."Platform" T0
```

XNL Output will be like this:

```
<screens>
   <IN1_PlatformID>14</IN1_PlatformID>
   <IN1_Name>My Name</IN1_Name>
</screens>
<screens>
   <IN1_PlatformID>15</IN1_PlatformID>
   <IN1_Name>My Name 2</IN1_Name>
</screens>
```

at c# side you need to insert a root node to read this.

```
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<rows>" + row["Screens"].ToString() + "</rows>");
```

After that, you can convert to dataset to read screens data easily:

```
var xmlReader = new System.Xml.XmlNodeReader(doc);
var dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlReader);
foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows){
    ...
}
```