# PostgreSQL - How to render MORE one to many relationships to XML

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I would like to create XML export from three tables of my database.

Tables: Customers, Orders, Payments. One customer may have more orders and more payments, of course.

I have already seen this great topic on stackoverflow: " [How to render one to many relationships to XML with PostgreSQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988052/how-to-render-one-to-many-relationships-to-xml-with-postgresql), which helped me a lot to find out how to build the query. However, the instructions there works for me only when I join table Customers either to Orders or to Payments, not to both of them. I didn't find out how to build the query, so I got output in the model like this:

```
<Customer>
<Name/>
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <id/>
        <date/>
        <content/>
    </Order>
</Orders>
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <id/>
        <date/>
        <amount/>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
</Customer>
```

Trying to do it this way:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name "Customer",
                    xmlelement(name "Name", c.name),
       xmlelement(name "Orders",
             xmlagg(xmlelement(name "Order",
                        xmlelement(name "id", o.id),                    
                        xmlelement(name "date", o.date),
                        xmlelement(name "content", o.content)))),
       xmlelement(name "Payments",                          
             xmlagg(xmlelement(name "Payment",
                        xmlelement(name "id", p.id),                        
                        xmlelement(name "date", p.date),
                        xmlelement(name "amount", p.amount)))))
from customers c
left join orders o on c.id = o.c_id
left join payments p on c.id = p.c_id
group by c.id, c.name;
```

...does not make sense. In case the customer has for instance 5 orders and 3 payments, it returns table with 15 rows. So there are 15 orders and 15 payments. I do not know how to use xmlaagg() function in the proper way. Being complete newbie in using XML, I do not even know if it is possible to create the output from database in the required way.

I will really appreciate any help.

Sample data:
(It is really just a quick example. Let's say there is no relation between orders and payments. In my real project there are other items and they have no relation. I need to see all payments and all orders.)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customers
(
    id      int,
    name    text
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE orders
(
    id      int,
    c_id    int, -- customer ID
    date    date,
    content text

);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE payments
(
    id      int,
    c_id    int, -- customer ID
    date    date,
    amount  numeric
);

INSERT INTO customers
VALUES(1, 'someguy');

INSERT INTO orders
VALUES
(1, 1, '1.1.2001', 'noteboook'),
(2, 1, '2.1.2001', 'tablet'),
(3, 1, '3.1.2001', 'phone'),
(4, 1, '3.1.2001', 'bag'),
(5, 1, '3.1.2001', 'shoes');

INSERT INTO payments
VALUES
(1, 1, '1.2.2001', '100'),
(2, 1, '2.2.2001', '200'),
(3, 1, '3.2.2001', '300');  

-- DROP TABLE payments;
-- DROP TABLE orders;
-- DROP TABLE customers;
```

Comment: Well, it definitively would. But unfortunately I can cope with SQL only at the moment. I know, it is time to learn some programming language, finally.

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I assumed you were using something like Ruby. Been looking at too many other posts in that tag today, sorry. Ignore my comment.

Comment: Thanks for reaction anyway!

Comment: Please show sample data as create table and insert statements. It's hard to write and test anything to help you without that.

Comment: Ok, I'll do in a while.

Comment: I hope, it is enough with just an simple example. If not, please, let me know, I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to aggregate before the join

```
select
    xmlelement(name "Customer",
        xmlelement(name "Name", name),
        orders, payments
    ) as the_xml
from
    customers
    left join (
        select c_id as id,
        xmlelement(name "Orders",
            xmlagg(xmlelement(name "Order",
                xmlelement(name "id", id),                    
                xmlelement(name "date", date),
                xmlelement(name "content", content)
                )
            )
        ) as orders
        from orders
        group by c_id
    ) o using (id)
    left join (
        select c_id as id,
        xmlelement(name "Payments",                          
            xmlagg(xmlelement(name "Payment",
                xmlelement(name "id", id),                        
                xmlelement(name "date", date),
                xmlelement(name "amount", amount)
                )
            )
        ) as payments
        from payments
        group by c_id
    ) p using (id)
```

Comment: Woohoo!!! Awesome! Thank you very much, I would never find the solution myself, probably, I tried so hard before, but it seems to me so clear now! You helped me a lot, cheers!